# Query efficiently on multiple sub-partitions

Tags: sql, partition

I have a database which creates hundreds of subpartitions per day. These partitions are named `P_20140116_00001, P_20140116_00002,` etc. Let's say these `00001 - 99999` are specific types of cars, from multiple brands.

Now, I have a select query that runs at the end of the day, but I feel it isn't optimal; I do give several filters, among others the date. However, I know which specific few partitions the data is in before running the query, but I let the query go through all the partitions (I think). I could specify the desired partitions by running another (very simple/fast) nested query. I just don't know if that's more efficient, but it feels like it would be. An example below:

For instance, I'd want a count of all Volkswagens that have been sold today. The select query I have right now only specifies that the indexed field 'brand' is Volkswagen, and that the partition to be used is today. However, I know that only `00003, 00103, and 00203` are types of `Volkswagen`, which means there is only going to be data that leads to a result in those 3 partitions.

My questions are:

- Would this query run through all the data in all other sub-partitions of the day, even though I know the query won't get any hits there?
- Is it possible for me to only target the partitions I know the desired data is in, by doing something like `P_[sysdate]_[substring in (select type_id from db.types where name = 'Volkswagen')] ?`
- Would this improve the efficiency of the query?
- Is there another way to get the desired result more efficiently than I am getting it right now?

Thanks a lot for the information!

Comment: I would start that it sounds like poor database design.  You should have individual columns such as VehicleBrand, DateSold, OtherField and NOT building into a string parts.  Build indexes on the criteria fields you would query from.